# AndroidでサービスでHTTP通信がRefuseされます

Tags: android, genymotion

ブロードキャストレシーバでインテントアクションのBOOT_COMPLETEDを受け取り、サービスを開始して、アプリのバックグランドでサーバとの通信を行いデータをダウンロードする、という処理を現在実装しています。

元々のアプリがアクティビティの中でやっていたデータのダウンロードをバックグランドで行いたいのですが、アクティビティの中で通信はうまくいくのですが、サービス内で通信をしようとすると

```
HTTPHOSTConectExcepton: Connection to http:// XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX refused
```

と表示されてうまくいきません。

Activityの中での通信はうまくいっているのに、サービス内だとうまくいかない理由がわかりません。

サービスはバインドせず、アクティビティと同一プロセス内別スレッドで処理をしています。
通信に必要なパラメータを渡す前にRefuseされるようで原因を探しています。

環境は
jdk1.8.0＿77
sdk compile version 23
target sdk version 23
Android Studio 1.5.1
Genymotion

Genymotionのエミュレータで開発しています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

自己解決しました。

英語のStack Overflowをあさっていたら

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514038/httphostconnectexception-connection-refused-android

の質問に行きつきました。

Metallica氏の回答にある、

AndroidManifest.xmlのpermission.INTERNETをコメントアウトする。

アプリを実行して、通信する

エラーを吐くのを確認。

コメントアウトを外して、実行（この時、adbコマンドではなくgenymotionのエミュレータを立ち上げなおす）。

で正常に動きました。

3日間ハマっていたこの問題はItellij14らへんのバグだそうです。